# Can someone help me to find a counter example that shows that $a \equiv b \mod m$ does not imply $(a+b)^m \equiv a^m +b^m \mod m$

Tags: number-theory

Can someone help me to find a counter example that shows that $a \equiv b \mod m$ does not imply $(a+b)^m \equiv a^m +b^m \mod m$. I have tried many different values but I can't seem to find one. I tried to prove it but I also cannot do it. Thanks.

Comment: Well you know it does imply that if $m$ is prime. So how about starting with $m$ a small composite number.

Comment: For example, take $m=6$. Then try a few pairs $(a,b)$. There are not many to try. You can clearly assume $0<a\le b<6$.

Comment: It can't be a prime and is trivial for $m=1$ so $m=4$ would be my first try.

Answer (score 3):

Take
$a=1,\,b=5,m=4$. Then, $a\pmod m = b\pmod m=1$ and:

$$(a+b)^m\pmod m=(1+5)^4\pmod4=1296\pmod4=0$$

$$(a^m+b^m)\pmod m=(1^4+5^4)\pmod4=626\pmod4=2$$

Comment: Why not just $a=b=1$?

Comment: Just used those values in a first try (I assumed $a\neq b$ for whatever reason), but as said in other comments, it should do!

Comment: It was neat to use $a\neq b$ - sorry the comment was terse.

Comment: Don't mind it, noting that $a=b$ can give counterexamples too is better for the OP!

Comment: $(a+b)^4 \equiv a^4 + b^4 \bmod 4$ iff $a$ or $b$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a=1$, $b=2$ and $m=6$.

$(a+b)^6 = a^6 + 6 a^5 b + 15 a^4 b^2 + 20 a^3 b^3 + 15 a^2 b^4 + 6 a b^5 + b^6$

$(a+b)^6 \equiv  a^6 - a^3 b^3 + b^6 \bmod 3$

If $(a+b)^6 \equiv a^6 + b^6 \bmod 6$, then $3$ must divide $a$ or $b$.

It is enough to take $a=1$ and $b=2$ to have  $(a+b)^6 \not\equiv  a^6 + b^6 \bmod 6$.

In general, $(a+b)^6 \equiv a^6 + b^6 \bmod 6$ iff $2$ divides $ab(a+b)$ and $3$ divides $ab$.